# C# equivalent to C `system()` standard library function

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, c#-4.0

I developed a C++ program which utilises an .exe file through the following code:

```
system (TestApplication input.txt > output.txt )
```

TestApplication is the exe here. `input.txt` is the file in the same project directory, and output.txt is generated in the same directory through the program.

I have to something similar to above in C# Gui (WPF) application. What's the substitute class for `system' in C# and how do we perform the same operation?

Comment: There is a System class in C#. Although I'm not sure what method you would use or if it contains a comparable method.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: Is there?  I'm only aware of a `System` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Diagnostics.Process` class represents the process in OS, and allows you to create new processes.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx for an example of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class, especially `Process.Start()`.

Comment: I looked at it earlier but was trying to find out a way to send the two file names for the exe, `input.txt` and `output.txt`. Any idea?

Comment: @Cipher: you put the arguments into the special ProcessStartInfo object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The class you are looking for is [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) for starting external processes in .NET.